# SelectBoxIt Custom icon not appearing on the selected Text

Tags: javascript, plugins

On the Selectboxit Page there is an example with custom icons. 
http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/#CustomIconSupport

So far so good.
I have a dropdown containing delivery modes each with an icon. I managed to have the icons show up within the options, but now when I select a option, the icon does not appear within the selectBoxIt Text when the dropdown closes.

The code for generating the options looks like this:

```
<option class="option option-delivery-code" 
    value="delivery-option-code" 
    data-iconurl="/_ui/all/media/img/my/icon/url.png"
    data-text='<span class="html-wrapper">Delivery Mode Name With some html tags </span>' >
</option>
```

Do I need to set any special options while creating the selectboxit in the JS Code to make it work?

Thanks for your help
Jan

Comment: I suggest you setup a jsFiddle for it, would be easier to help you dude :)

Comment: so here is a fiddle with the example from the plugin page and it seems to be working..so it is probably some problem with my code.. http://jsfiddle.net/279CX/ for now I solved it without the plugin, but I might come back to it..